# Xamarin Initialization Order

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, initialization

Within my Xamarin.Forms project, I've got a central data model called `DataStore`, which permanently retrieves JSON data from a web socket, transforms it into objects and stores them in a `Dictionary`. I need to access this `DataStore` from multiple ViewModels and Views. In order to achieve this, I did the following:

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace Foo
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public DataStore dataStore { get; }

        public static App current = (App)Application.Current;

        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataStore = new DataStore();

            MainPage = new MainPage();
        }
    }
}
```

And the `DataStore` itself has the following events:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class DataStore
    {
        Dictionary<int, Target> targetDict;
        public EventHandler<Target> targetAdded;
        public EventHandler<Target> targetRemoved;
    }
}
```

So I can connect to the `DataModel`'s events within all the ViewModels or Views where I need them as follows:

```
namespace Foo
{
    public class TargetMap : Map
    {
        public List<CustomPin> customPins { get; set; }

        public TargetMap() : base()
        {
            customPins = new List<CustomPin>();

            App.current.dataStore.targetAdded += onTargetAdded;
            App.current.dataStore.targetRemoved += onTargetRemoved;
        }

        void onTrackRemoved(object sender, Target t)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }

        void onTrackAdded(object sender, Track t)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm running into null-pointer-exceptions, which tells me I'm having a problem with initialization order.

Question is:

Where and how would be the "Xamarin" way to initialize a central data layer component like the `DataStore` if it needs to be accessed from multiple ViewModels and Views? Would you just make it static?

Any hint much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand of your issue, you have two options

1) Make a singleton out of your DataStore (so yeah a static property) to make it available from anywhere in your app

2) Make an abstraction of your DataStore, and inject that abstraction at startup (better solution imo)

However, no matter what solution you choose, you will still have an initialization issue.
What you should do (in your viewmodels), is call a DataStore method to initialize it if necessary, before trying to access any data.

Comment: Thank you! Your second approach sounds very promising, I don't quite understand it, tho. I'm presuming by "abstraction" you mean to add a more abstract superclass, but how does it help me? I don't understand the "injection" part, yet.

Comment: By "abstraction" I mean making your DataStore implement an interface, say "IDataStore". When your object implements that interface, you can then use an IoC (Inversion of Control) library which will let you "inject" your DataStore into any viewmodels, using its interface.
This way, if need be in the future, you could replace your DataStore, with a DataStore2 (while still implementing the IDataStore interface), and you wouldn't have any line of refactoring to do anywhere in your app. IoC is one of the most common and usefull tools in Xamarin, you should check it out if you can

Comment: Just to be clear, IoC is not specific to Xamarin. It's just that we use it a lot in Xamarin projects, because of the cross-platform aspect of the technology

Comment: Ok, I knew IoC and I've used it in various projects before. However, I'm coming from a C++ background (hence the lower case methods and member names), which raises a new question in my mind: How can I make use of c# events in interfaces? Can an interface have eventhandlers? Or should I create methods like `subscribeToXXX(callback)`?

Comment: Events are a bit of a pain in the ass in C#/.NET. What I would advise to achieve the same thing (i.e broadcasting informations to "clients") in a xamarin project is using a "Messenger" (you can have a look at MvvmCross IMvxMessenger implementation to get the general idea). The behavior you want will be the same, but it is cleaner to use than events, and is completely compatible with IoC

Comment: Oh I just found you can actually simply add `EventHandler`s to interfaces and then simply use them in sub-classesm which I find nice. However, I've got a follow up question: I've seen lots of packages requiring a static `Foo.Init()` call in either `MainActivity.cs` and/or `AppDelegate.cs`. Personally, I would put my `IStore` initialization there. Is that valid/good/acceptable practice?

Comment: Those Foo.Init() calls are usually for "short" inits (like API key initialization etc). Since you're loading data I'm assuming it will be a rather long method execution so you will still need a way in your IDataStore to know if your object has finished loading data. I'd try to make that operation as late as possible, to avoid making too much work on app startup (which might lower your user experience when starting the app)

Comment: Actually I'd consider it to be rather short. It's 1.) OAuth using `HttpClient` and then 2.) setting up a websocket using `SCClient.Socket` and then wait for incoming data.

Comment: Making an HTTP call for OAuth is already what I consider to be "long" in a mobile app. Rather than doing it on app startup, if you have a Splashscreen, add it there. If you dont have one, consider adding it maybe ?

Comment: Ok I see, I wanted to add a splash screen anyway. Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I wanted to use the short `.Init()` call to simply instanciate my store, so all the views and viewmodels can "connect" to it, and then I would call something like `Store.connect()` within the splash. Would that be the way to go?

Comment: Yes that is definitely how I would approach this